# How to prove that my combiner vector is $\mathbf H \vec f $?

Tags: digital-communications

When my received signal is $y=\mathbf H \vec f x+\vec n$,they we need a combiner vector in the receiver,how do i prove that combiner vector $\vec w$ is $\mathbf H \vec f $?

After the received signal multiply the combiner,the formula will become this

$\vec w^H y=\vec w^H\mathbf H \vec f x+\vec w^H\vec n$

$\mathbf H$ is a $2 \times 7$ matrix,and it is channel

$\vec f$ is a $7 \times 1$ vector,and it is beamforming

$x$ is a $1 \times 1$ value,and it is signal

Comment: Hi! Um, that claim from my point of view is plain wrong, so you can't prove it?

Comment: where is wrong?because $H \vec f $ actually produce a new channel $H_1$,and the maximize ratio combing coefficient should be $H^H$,i saw p6~p7 in this  reference ,https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~rsadve/Notes/DiversityReceive.pdf